# Charge and Current in an electrical circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-current, charge

This is a question about the differences between charge and current.

- First, why is current a more fundamental, or 'base' unit than the charge? It seems like a charge particle) would be more fundamental than 'charge per second', so why isn't the Coulomb used instead?
- What is the SI unit for 'the total amount of charge' that has been pushed through a circuit? In my head it would be number of electrons that have went from the positive potential different to zero (similar to a ball dropping to the ground for a certain height).
- Is there some sort of relationship between the total amount of charge that has went through a circuit and the potential energy released by the battery? I assume they would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a question about the differences between charge and current.

Actually, it is several questions :)

> First, why is current a more fundamental, or 'base' unit than the charge? It seems like a charge particle) would be more fundamental than 'charge per second', so why isn't the Coulomb used instead?

Historically current could be measured more accurately than charge. So it made practical sense to choose current as the base unit despite the theoretical preference for charge as the base unit. SI is intended to be practical above all, so practical concerns won out over theoretical concerns.

> What is the SI unit for 'the total amount of charge' that has been pushed through a circuit? In my head it would be number of electrons that have went from the positive potential different to zero (similar to a ball dropping to the ground for a certain height).

The coulomb.

> Is there some sort of relationship between the total amount of charge that has went through a circuit and the potential energy released by the battery? I assume they would be the same.

They are not the same but closely related: $E=VQ$ where $E$ is the energy $V$ is the voltage of the battery and $Q$ is the charge

Comment: thanks, this is a great answer. So for the `VQ` -- that would be the total amount of work done by that circuit over time, in joules? And finally, the Power (avg) would that divided by the time the circuit has been running?

Comment: Yes, exactly...